# Installed GPO Administrative Template is missing from the editor

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016

I have this template installed:

[image]

However, it fails to appear in the editor:

[image]

I tried downloading and running the .MSI from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3088114/how-to-use-group-policy-to-configure-windows-update-delivery-optimizat), but that didn't help matters.

This template appears to be installed correctly. How can I enable it in GPEdit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must copy `DeliveryOptimization.admx` and `en-us\DeliveryOptimization.adml` in `c:\windows\PolicyDefinitions\DeliveryOptimization.admx` and `c:\windows\PolicyDefinitions\en-us\DeliveryOptimization.adml`.

However, you should really consider creating a [Central Store for Administrative Templates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3087759/how-to-create-and-manage-the-central-store-for-group-policy-administra), so you don't need to copy those files on every computers running the GPO Editor.

Comment: Very good, thank you.